# Is the 2D array defined in java? If yes then what will be the output?

Tags: java, arrays

```
 public class Main {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       int[][] numbers = {{1, 2, 3} , {4, 5, 6, 7}}; //Is it defined?
       int x = numbers[0][3]; // Should the output be 0?
       System.out.println(x);
   }
}
```

Comment: That is a [Jagged Array](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/jagged-array-in-java/).  So `numbers[1][3]` would be defined (as the number 7), but `numbers[0,3]` would cause an array out of bounds exception, since there is no fourth element in the first row.

Comment: In any case, it's easy enough to check: https://repl.it/@robertwharvey/Jagged-Arrays-in-Java#Main.java.  Notice that it compiles (indicating that the array declaration succeeded), but throws a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` at line 4

Comment: *"Should the output be 0?"* Why don't you **try it**, i.e. run the code and see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

you may take a look here into the official oracle specification:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html

When you take a look on chapter (array access) you will see that:
"All arrays are 0-origin. An array with length n can be indexed by the integers 0 to n-1."

Comment: That does not answer his question.

Comment: Well, it kinda does, partially.

Answer (score 0):

A 2D array is really an array of arrays.  So you can do this.

```
int[][] arr = new int[4][];
arr[0] = new int[] {1,2,3};
arr[1] = new int[] {4,5,6,7};
arr[2] = new int[] {8,9,10,11,12,13};
arr[3] = new int[] {14,15};
```

And to print them.

```
for (int[] a : arr) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
}
```

Prints

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6, 7]
[8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
[14, 15]
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically, there are no two-dimensional arrays.  What you can have is an array of arrays; this is conveyed precisely by the `[][]` syntax.

In your example,

```
  int[][] numbers = {{1, 2, 3} , {4, 5, 6, 7}};
```

the 0'th element of numbers, i.e., `numbers[0]`, is a 3-element array, whereas `numbers[1]`, is a 4-element array.

Accessing `numbers[0][3]` will raise an exception, since 3 is out of bounds for the 3-element array.

Reference to Java Language Specification: [Chapter 10, Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-10.html).